# Rails get value from hash based on table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think the best way for me to explain this question is with example.  Here is a simple method with a hash:

```
def getValues(table)
    allColumns = {
       'User' => ['first_name', 'last_name'],
       'Vehicle' => ['make', 'model', 'id'],
    }
end
```

I am trying to pass in the table and based on that table return a range of values.  I would like to know what would be (performance-wise) the best way to accomplish this.  Is it using a switch statement, if/else, some sort of loop?  If you come up with an answer, please be as kind to include an example so that I may understand better.

Comment: What is the format of this table?

Comment: the format should not matter, all it is doing grabbing the name of the table and based on the name it gets the item from the hash shown above.

Comment: Are you hoping to return all columns for the table, or a predefined subset?

Comment: the predefined subset that is shown in the hash.  The table has many more columns, but i only want values that are shown in the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to rename the parameter first, maybe to `table_name` or something more descriptive.
Second it is kind of a convention in ruby to use method names separated by `_`, and avoid using camelCase as another languages.
Third, i would put the list on a constant variable or something, and just reference it inside the method.

Then you can look up the values of some hash based on a key just by using `hash[key]`.

```
LIST = {
  'User' => ['first_name', 'last_name'],
  'Vehicle' => ['make', 'model', 'id'],
}

def get_values(table_name)
  LIST[table_name]
end
```

Hash lookup by key is probably one of the most performant operations you could do with a collection, so there is no need to worry about it.

Comment: since I am passing the entire table, and not just the table name, will this still work or do I have to convert the table to table_name string before it will search?  How automatic is this in rails?  If I have to convert, which method do I use to get the table name?

Comment: @Bagzli If you have a class like `class SomeModel`, there is a method called `.name` that strigify the class name, so `SomeModel.name` should return you `"SomeModel"`, a string representation of the class.